# How to define type synonyms of int, float etc. for various roles in F#?

Tags: f#

I would like to use simple types like 'int' in various roles in a way that the compiler would prevent me to mix up variables of different roles inadvertently. Using units of measure seems to offer a (light) way to solve it.

```
[<Measure>]
type xcoordinate
[<Measure>]
type ycoordinate

type xci = int<xcoordinate>
type yci = int<ycoordinate>

let fnc (x:xci) (y:yci) = ...

// Now 'fnc' can be called only with a proper x-y coordinate pair.
// Is there any way to use the type synonyms to coerce an 'int' to  
// int<xcoordinate> instead of writing 2<xcoordinate>, for instance?
```

Comment: Something like `LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure` or the equivalent int functions?

Comment: Multiplying by `1<measure>` is pretty helpful. Also, are you sure that units of measure are the right solution to your problem? They don't seem like they would be that particularly useful in your case.

Comment: Sounds like a good use for phantom types: http://gettingsharper.de/2015/02/07/type-system-for-the-win-phantom-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "obvious" thought, I have at least, is to use single case discriminated unions.

```
type XCoordinate = XCoordinate of int
type YCoordinate = YCoordinate of int

let fnc (x:XCoordinate) (y:YCoordinate) = ()

let x = 1 
let y = 1

let xc = XCoordinate(x)
let yc = YCoordinate(y)


let resNoCompile = fnc x y //wont compile

let res = fnc xc yc //works as expected
```

You will still not be able to mix ints and floats in same role. I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is even better than using units of measure. The only snag is 'let res = fnc XCoordinate(x) YCoordinate(y)' does not compile but that's another story.

Comment: @AttilaKaroly add some more () like let res = fnc (XCoordinate(x)) (YCoordinate(y)). It can be done with: let res = XCoordinate(x) |> fnc <| YCoordinate(y) too. But again thats not like it gets prettier ;-)

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis in `XCoordinate(x)`; you can write that as `XCoordinate x` as if it was a function call. Thus, `let res = fnc (XCoordinate x) (YCoordinate y)` will work, and that should be pretty enough.